# Is it possible to implement path-aware https blocking with MITM

Tags: networking, pi-hole

The popular pi-hole uses DNS to block certain hosts from showing ads. It seems, that as a response, lots of content providers have started hosting ads from the same host they serve content from. (instagram.com, most amp sites, etc...).

Would it be practical/possible to install a custom root cert on a device and proxy all traffic. Unwrapping the request and blocking individual requests based on the url path?

I understand this might be problematic as a piece of software as it's undermining the security of requests, but if something like an iOS device is never going to have an option for more granular request blocking, is this a possible alternate approach?

Comment: That's possible and it could also be done on the host itself with a proxy.  If you only want to block ads in a web browser, however, an adblock browser addon is usually easier to set-up and maintain (subscription to filter lists...).